# How can should I pass two functions as parameters, both can be optional, in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I want to build up an flexible small API to backend for the client. To provide some convenience in using default success-/error- handlers or writing own ones, I planned to support the user with the option to pass both handlers one or none. I tried as follows.

*Snippet of file "API" to backend:*

```
function someRPCcall(method, url, data, successHandler, failedHandler) {

 // checking if successHandler and failedHandler are defined and passed functions

if (paramType1 === 'undefined' || paramType1 === 'null') {
            successHandlerHelper = defaultSuccessRESTHandler;
        } else if (paramType1 === 'function') {
            successHandlerHelper = successHandler;
        } 
if (paramType2 === 'undefined' || paramType2 === 'null') {
            failedHandlerHelper = defaultFailedRESTHandler;
        } else if (paramType2 === 'function') {
            failedHandlerHelper = failedHandler;
        }

        ajaxCall(method, url, data, successHandlerHelper, failedHandlerHelper);
}

  function ajaxCall(method, url, data, success, failed) {
        console.log("in ajaxCcall");
        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: data,
            url: url,
            success: success,
            error: failed
            dataType: "json"
        });
        console.log("ajaxCall - call done");
    }
```

*Snippet of file of client code*

someRPCcall will be indirectly called by functions in another file:

```
someFunctionRPCcall("bla", null, errorHandler);
```

whereas searchWordOccurrenceRPCcall is calling someRPCcall

Above the failureHandler would be a selfdefined Handler, but following calls also should be possible:

```
someFunctionRPCcall("bla", null, successHandler, errorHandler);
someFunctionRPCcall("bla", null, successHandler);
someFunctionRPCcall("bla", null);
```

I heard about taking an object, in which the functions would be defined....

This code does not call the self defined handlers, but I guess this is another problem (using apply is missing or something like that)
The question I wanted to put here is:
Is there a way to pass both functions as optional parameters? How about that proposal useing objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you can get your function to take an object, eg:

```
function someRPCcall(args) {
    var method = args.method || "POST";
    var url = args.url || "default";
    var data = args.data || {};
    var successHandler = args.success || defaultSuccessRESTHandler;
    var failedHandler = args.failed || defaultFailedRESTHandler;

    ajaxCall(method, url, data, successHandler, failedHandler);
}
```

You will notice above that if a property is not present on the `args` object then it is given a default.

Then call it as follows:

```
someRPCcall({
    url : "the url",
    failed: function() { ... }
});
```

Of course, you could throw an exception if some values are not set, eg `url`:

```
function someRPCcall(args) {
    if(!args.url) { 
        throw "url must be set";
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one object as parameter seems weird to me (even if I believe, that it works). How about passing only the functions in an object and the other parameters still as simple parameters?

Comment: Yeah, you could do that - but I think it would be less weird to pass a single object. That's what the jQuery `$.ajax` function above does!